# Change default papersize not working, using c#

Tags: c#, printing

I'm using this code to add a new papersize:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12229/Adding-custom-paper-sizes-to-named-printers?msg=3061384

```
MJMCustomPrintForm.AddCustomPaperSizeToDefaultPrinter("test1", (float)100, (float)200);
```

My problem is, when I add new papersize, the defaultpapersize changed to new one.

[image]

I use this code to changed to "Letter" but it's not working. Even I run it as Administrator.

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
PaperSize letter = ps.PaperSizes.Cast<PaperSize>().Where(x => x.PaperName == "Letter").FirstOrDefault();
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = letter;
```

Did I miss something? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Print PrintDocument.Net provides a very simple and easy to use, but in the actual application development often need to customize the paper, especially the need for paper printing. This problem has troubled me for a long time, by referring to the relevant data and several attempts, discovered actually very simple.

```
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
PrintDocument letter = new PrintDocument();
letter.PrinterSettings = ps; 

printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 315, 300);
```

Try it another way.

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("Custom", 315, 300);
pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.letter = 119;
pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.letter = 119;
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
```